# Is it is possible to import xml directly into a freestylejob via jenkins jobdsl

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to modify the builders section of a freestyle job via jobdsl. I am able to modify this via jobdsl as demonstrated by this page (https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block). However is it possible for me to inject defined xml directly into the freestyle job.

I tried injecting the xml via a configure step. Where buildXml is the builders xml expanded and configured.

```
    job.configure({ config ->
        config / builders << {
            buildXml
        }
    })
```

The expected result is to have the job generated with with the build steps included.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but know that the configure block returns a `groovy.util.Node` . So if it is at all possible I guess you need to do something with that object. Did you try "append()" ?